# How to achieve "bring to front" for a list in aspx page that has Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, z-index, swfobject

Above is the top portion of the page that I am referring to in this posting.
In this image, everything from the table that has "step one" are loaded from a SWF file using javascript. This javascript uses Jquery and files like "swfobject.js".

Issue is when page is loaded, "Shop by" control has a list of values but in this page, when user clicks on "Shop by" it is not shown. The contents are displayed but is coming to front. I tried to set 'zindex', 'absoulte postioning' but no success.

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try wrapping your SWF object in a div, setting that div z-index behind the one you want in front? Also remember that you must set the div you are using the z-index on to position:relative; for the z-index to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it's about `wmode="transparent"` thing in your swf.
since i dont see your html here, how you call your swf, check this http://www.flashdesignerzone.com/tutorials/t1026.php maybe it helps